# could an algorithm that writes algorithms be written?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Could an algorithm that writes algorithms be written? Wikipedia says: An algorithm is an effective method expressed as a finite list of well-defined instructions for calculating a function. Starting from an initial state and initial input (perhaps empty), the instructions describe a computation that, when executed, proceeds through a finite number of well-defined successive states, eventually producing "output" and terminating at a final ending state. So could an algorithm (an effective method expressed as a finite list of well-defined instructions for calculating a function) that writes effective methods expressed as finite lists of well-defined instructions for calculating functions?

Comment: I think (maybe mistakenly) that the question suits [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) the best. Even if the question has some philosophical potential, in my opinion there's very little of it.

Comment: To my mind, genetic algorithms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) do this.

Comment: This question is primarily mathematical in nature and is of relevance to computer science.  It is best to pose it to computer scientists or mathematicians, not philosophers.

Comment: Sure. "print "print 'hello world'"" is one such. That's a program whose output is a program. There is nothing very interesting about this. So you would have to be more specific if you want something interesting to come of this.

Comment: Most certainly - because I am one (and you are). If it can happen by evolution that wasn't for creating algorithms but for survival it must be possible to create one intentionally.

Comment: There are even programs called *Quine programs* that print themselves. https://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It may appear to be possible to write an algorithm writing algorithm.  In actuality, such an algorithm does not exist, due to the halting problem.

While you can write an algorithm that outputs a list of instructions, the output is limited by the original algorithm, and only applies to a specific pre-defined goal.

So, you cannot write an algorithm where you give it an arbitrary goal and it constructs an algorithm to reach the goal.

Comment: I don't think that the halting problem is relevant here.

Comment: The halting problem is definitely relevant if the question is -- is there an algorithm which, given any problem as input, outputs an algorithm which solves that problem. Then the halting problem says that there's no such universal algorithm (this could perhaps be made more precise by putting it in terms of arithmetical vs recursive/recursively enumerative sets)

Comment: As a sidenote, this is evidence AI isn't possible.  If it were possible to replace programmers, with all the brainpower directed at computer science we'd have discovered an algorithm to replace programmers by this point.  But we haven't, and the number of programmers is increasing rapidly.  Therefore, programmers can solve a class of problems that algorithms cannot.  Since AI is a kind of algorithm, true AI that replicates human intelligence is impossible.

Comment: @yters: You'd have thought, then, that Einstein's famous equation might have been developed some time in the previous couple thousand of years of science.

Comment: @J.P., I do not see how the halting problem is related to this question, since neither a human can write an algorithm for the halting problem.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by 'writes algorithms'. As long as you don't mind an algorithm which only writes a single algorithm, then it's easy. Here's one:

- **STEP 1**. Write down "STEP 1: Write down 'Hello World' "
- **STEP 2**. Write down "FINISH"
- **FINISH**

What happens when we follow this algorithm? We write down this:

- **STEP 1**. Write down 'Hello World'
- **FINISH**

which is an algorithm.

#### More interesting cases

In fact, algorithms which write algorithms are pretty common in computer programming (if you think of a program as an algorithm). They're called [*preprossors*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor). A very simple program in a language called a *macro language* gives instructions for writing a program in another language.

(We might also think of compilers as algorithms which write algorithms, but these are less interesting. They take an algorithm described in one language as an input, then output the *same* algorithm, just described in a different language (machine language))

Comment: Why the downvote? (This would be helpful for anyone reading this -- if I've made a mistake it will be useful for people -- and me -- to know what it was!)

Comment: You did great. I can't understand the downvote either.

Answer (score 1):

There are programs that write other programs. There are some books that discuss stuff like this and have philosophical content, such as "Godel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid" by Douglas R. Hofstadter.

Programming itself is philosophically interesting. If you want to test whether you understand something one way to do this is to write down a set of instructions that describe your best guess about it that a computer can follow. The computer will then execute your instructions and if it produces the correct result your understanding has passed the test.

Similar considerations apply to programs that write programs: writing such programs is called metaprogramming. Different programming languages provide different facilities for metaprogramming and represent different philosophies on how easy it should be to do metaprogramming. For example, many lispy programming languages make it relatively easy to do metaprogrmamming by having programs written as data structures that can be read by the lisp reader:

http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html.

Other programming languages make metaprogramming harder because you have to do things like write strings that represent the code you want the program to write. Having worse facilities for metaprogramming makes it harder to test your understanding of how to program because you have to write more code that is not directly relevant to the problem you're interested in but is required to set it up, then you have to debug the mistakes that result from you writing it by hand.

Comment: Why the downvote? This gave a useful reference to presumably relevant material (G.E.B.). If that's not relevant, whoever downvoted should write a comment to say so (I've not read it, so I don't know one way or another).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you've described a general structure of a certain algorithm. But the 'devil' is in the details: neural networks are probably the closest to what you are asking; its in this manner that they 'learn'; one could say though that the general structure doesn't change could such an algorithm rewrite itself such that it can no longer re-write itself - so it has changed its general structure? I think so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strict sense in which you can say that no computational process produces a (truly) new algorithm.

I'd usually think of the process of one algorithm generating another as involving:

1. Starting with the generating algorithm, and maybe some data (if you want to make that distinction).
2. Construct the "new algorithm".
3. Apply the new algorithm to some new data.

However, this process can be always be executed by a machine that just recreates (simulates) this whole process on demand, i.e. starts with item 1. and ends up with the results of item 3.  Thus there isn't anything new or novel in the "new algorithm" that wasn't already specified in the initial data.  So in a very formal, narrow sense, an algorithm cannot create a truly new algorithm; of the content of the later algorithm is encoded, in some manner, in the initial algorithm (and any data used to configure that initial algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

In a sense algorithms that write algorithms, or more accurately programs that write programs, have been around since the late 1950's in the form of Fortran compilers (or whatever the first program translation program was - open to argument). A Fortran compiler would take a program specification (written in Fortran) and produce program in the form of an executable.

This early, basic program translation might not seem like a "program writing a program", but taking the concept further, using higher level, more abstract human specifications, even in the form of graphical languages or diagrams, we arrive at an abstract human specification (or request) resulting in a program. We can put further distance between the human request and the result with systems that could handle requests like "train a neural net with this input".

All of the above approaches to program generation, a human has decided a new program is needed, initiated the process and provided some guidance. To take the next step on the ladder of artificial intelligence, a machine would have to determine the need for a new program and guide its production. I don't know of this being done at present, but there's nothing extremely tricky about it that would rule this out. It wouldn't surprise me at all if it was being done right now, possibly in a research context.

Comment: In my answer above I talk about "programs" instead of "algorithms" because an algorithm is of limited use without  data structures (or databases, knowledge bases or trained neural networks). Algorithms make up parts of  programs and we don't make many complex systems out of just algorithms.